# FAT32: Unable to use the whole partition size

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32

I recently bought a 8GB USB flash disk. I created a fat32 filesystem (using `mkfs.vfat`) on the whole drive (`/dev/sdb1`).

`df -h` shows approximately 8GB available, but when I try to extract an archive on the disk, the kernel raises `No space left on device` exceptions at about 812MB of occupation, and `df` stills show plenty of space available.

I tried the same manipulation using an `ext3` filesystem, without any problem.

Comment: That's definitely not hardware (unless i'm incredibly unlucky). I tried with an other brand new usb drive, with exactly the same result. The system claims `"No space left on device"` at `812MB`.

Comment: I don't know where the answer is gone, so here is the mkfs command I used :
`mkfs.fsck -F 32 -n katana /dev/sdb1`